# UnfriendFinder alternative?

Tags: facebook, browser-addons

There were an browser addon which showed message when someone from Facebook unfriended you. However now it is dead. Is there any alternative to track my friends?

Comment: Have you already tried the [social fixer](http://socialfixer.com/) browser extension? That has a 'friend tracker' option that I believe works for both facebook and twitter.

Comment: That app had to remove the "friend tracker" functionality due to pressure from Facebook. 

Another browser extension that has "unfriend" notification functionality is FB Purity : http://fbpurity.com

Answer (score 2):

There is no "UnfriendFinder" alternative at the moment.

However, you can export your friendlist to a `.xls` or `.csv` file. If you want to check, you just have to export your friendlist another time and compare it with the first one.

This solution is very basic but it does work well.

Answer (score 1):

There may not be any addon which does the job but there are several userscripts which you can use. Here is a list of few of them :

- http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/153830
- http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/124219

There are serveral others available at **userscripts.org**.

To install a userscript you will need **Greasemonky** installed. It is available both as an addon for Firefox and extension for Chrome.

Try each one out to see which one work out best for you.

Comment: I've just installed, does not work.

Comment: Which one did you try. You should try the second one, seems quite popular and recently updated.

Comment: I've tried the most popular and recently updated one, in other words the second one. It opens a new tab in a loophole http://www.unfriendfinder.net/ again and again. Nowhere is listed any unfriended friends.